# xamarin.forms complex DataBinding

Tags: xamarin.forms

i have a problem with DataBinding on Xamarin.Forms and i hope you can help me out.

I have two classes calles angebot (quotation) and adresse (address) looks like this:

```
public class angebot
{
  public string ADRESSE { get; set; }
  public string ANGEBOT { get; set; }
  // ... and more
}

public class adresse
{
   public string ADRESSE { get; set; }
   public string NAME { get; set; }
  // ...and more
}
```

These classes are used on another class for data holding:

```
private IEnumerable<recDataClass> recData = null;
private class recDataClass
{
    public Database.Tabellen.angebot angebotData = null;
    public Database.Tabellen.adresse adresseData = null;
}
```

After filled the data classes with data i joined them togeteher in the recData class.

```
            recData =angData.Join (adrData, 
                angebot => angebot.ADRESSE,
                adresse => (adresse.ADRESSE), 
                (angebot, adresse) => new recDataClass {    
                    angebotData = angebot,
                    adresseData = adresse
                });
```

Till this step everything is working really fine. recData holds the correct data.
Now i want to set the databinding for my xaml

```
recDataPage.BindingContext = recData.ElementAt(index);
```

Now to my question. How do i set the databinding in my xaml correctly to show my data?

```
<Entry Text="{Binding ANGEBOT}" x:Name="enAngebot" Keyboard="Text" WidthRequest="350" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />

Text="{Binding ANGEBOT}"
Text="{Binding recData.angebotData.ANGEBOT}"
Text="{Binding angebotData.ANGEBOT}"
```

are not working

What i'm doing wrong?

Thx forward

Answer (score 0):

`DataBinding` only works on `property`, so you should change the fileds on `recDataClass` to `property` like:

```
private class recDataClass
{
    public Database.Tabellen.angebot angebotData {get;set;}
    public Database.Tabellen.adresse adresseData {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: aaaahhhhh. Thank you very much !!
What a mistake :-)